# Jquery Editable Call Action before-save

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, inline-editing

I have integrated jQuery editable (X-editable - v1.5.0 ) in my project.
There are 2 option in my drop-down list, one is accept and other is reject.

If user selects "Accept" then the corresponding record should get accepted (Quite eassy).

If user selects "Reject" then the corresponding record should get rejected, but there is a twist. If user is rejecting the record, then it should mention the reason before rejecting. (Pop-up Modal).

I could not find the way I could get pop-up details before saving the result. (onBeforeSave method for Inline Edit.)

Please help on this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any related code or fiddle??

Comment: I don't have fiddle URL now...